# Properties with Spring @Configuration

Tags: java, spring, configuration, properties, dependency-injection

If I have a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` coming via an XML file, is it possible to have my Spring `@Configuration` use that as its source of properties for all the beans it handles?

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(value = { "x.y.z })
@ImportResource({ "classpath:remote-properties/applicationContext.xml",})
public class CoreConfiguration implements TransactionManagementConfigurer {

    @Resource(name = "com.c.h.c.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer")
    public PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer pp;

   @Bean
    public PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer propertiesFactoryBean() {
        return pp;
    }
}
```

With the above, it never hits my breakpoint on `pp`. If I remove the `@Bean` and the method, I can verify that `pp` is populated. So how I can I register it with the configuration?

Comment: Have you reviewed http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?107194-PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer-and-javconfig

Comment: @Rob I can't use a properties file directly. I have to either use a PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer bean from that app content, OR load a properties file that has the url of the second properties file and then load that properties file. I know it sounds ridiculous, but that's the team I'm on solved a multiple environment issue.

Comment: @Rob More over, I need the properties not just in the '@Configuration' class itself, but available for use when the '@ComponentScan' does its magic on '@Service' annotated classes (so that '@Value' annotations will get correctly populated).

Comment: Which version of Spring are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel pretty stupid. I was missing a right curly brace on one of my `@Value` annotations. I can't imagine how many times I looked at that and missed it.

So, having a `PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer` in an app context you `@ImportResource` on will work without any problems. You don't even need to bring it in as a `@Resource`.